# Как проверить что boost::asio::ip::address принадлежит заданой сети?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Как определить что заданный адрес *address* принадлежит заданной сети *network*?

```
auto networkAddress = asio::ip::make_address_v4("192.168.144.0");
auto network = asio::ip::make_network_v4(networkAddress, 24);
auto address = asio::ip::make_address_v4("192.168.144.101");
```

Также интересует есть ли возможность сделать это кроссверсионно (v4 и v6). Отсутствие version-independent класса для ip::network, как это сделано для ip::address, намекает что нет.

Comment: Так у вас же уже вроде правильный код записан - извлекаете адрес сети из адреса и сравниваете.

Comment: Из ip::address не возможно извлечь адрес сети - нету такой функции, да и не логично ее наличие. Можно зайти с другой стороны. Зная длину префикса можно из адреса создать ещё один экземпляр ip::network_v4 для известного префикса. А тогда уже сравнивать ip::network_v4::canonical для обоих экземпляров. Но мне это выглядит слишком многословным.